# Pass objects as POST variables from jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to pass a two objects and a string as post parameters to php.

This is how my code is now:

```
var obj1 = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'};

var obj2 = {'e':'f', 'g':'h'};

var url = 'hello';

dataParams = { 
    object1: obj1,
    object2: obj2,
    url: url
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/sample.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: dataParams
});
```

In sample.php

```
echo $_POST['url'] gives hello
echo $_POST['object1'] or json_decode($_POST['object1']) gives null.
echo $_POST['object2'] or json_decode($_POST['object2']) gives null.
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: similar post that might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265826/passing-json-object-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: In your post there's a simple error, you don't close ' after object1 and object2. Try to print $_POST and analyze the output

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($_POST)` in your php sacript to see what json sends you?

Comment: Would you mind posting whole code? because i can't see 'url' in the object that you have passed as 'data'.

Comment: @gafreax it just has the url property

Comment: @AndreschSerj: it just has the url property
array(1) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}

Comment: @user1708762: I have edited the code. Forgot to add url

Comment: @Jazmin you forgot in the original code also? i mean the code that you are trying to run.

Comment: @user1708762: no its there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all ur quick responses.

In my code I am populating the obj1 and obj2 from the DOM input fields. I have initialized them as arrays instead of objects.

```
obj1 = [] instead of obj1 ={}
```

After making that change, its working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
method = 'POST'
```

when it should be:

```
type: 'POST'
```

Also, echo $_POST['object1'] will return 'Array'! If you want to see the values, use print_r($_POST['object1']), ok?
;)

Comment: BTW, why are you using DataType? Are you going to return a json object ?

Comment: I have to return a json object in future. But even after removing the dataType property its not working

Comment: try running the JSON.stringify also on the dataParams, or enclose object1 and object2 in '', that should do the trick!

Comment: another thing: .post does not need a method attribute, it is already a post! ;)

Comment: when I add JSON.stringif for dataParams, I couldn't retrieve url property also now.

Comment: ok, got the problem: you are using method = 'POST', but it should be type: 'POST' instead! I'll will just edit my answer, ok?

Comment: Ya it was a stupid mistake. But it dint affect the result. Still the same error. But I found something new now. If i have obj1 as {'3':'4', 'c':'d'}

The result is like {null, null, null, null, 4} 

This happens without using JSON.stringfy in any places

Comment: BTW: echo $_POST['object1'] will return 'Array'! If you want to see the values, you need to do print_r($_POST['object1']), ok?

Comment: I have just tested the code, and it works fine! This is what I did:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <script>
  var obj1 = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'};
  var obj2 = {'e':'f', 'g':'h'};
  var url = 'hello';
  dataParams = { 
   object1: obj1,
   object2: obj2,
   url: url
  }
  $.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost/test.php',
   dataType: 'text',
   type: 'POST',
   data: dataParams,
   success: function(data){
    alert(data);
   }
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: ya ok. Thanks. It was returning either empty array or null, but i dint realise my stupidity at that time.